# Create Shape model button in CSS3

Tags: html, css

How to create below the button in CSS3. I don't know this is possible or not.

Thanks.

[image]

**Update:**

[See below the link](http://jsfiddle.net/anglimass/ARnc4/)

1. Normal
2. Button

Normal case support css3 but not support button.

Comment: First off you shouldn't have 2 elements with the same id, i.e. `talkbubble`

Comment: Use rather images: http://jsbin.com/ugikaw/7/edit

Answer (score 0):

I have try to make some test, look and tell me.
http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/ndbJQ/1/

Comment: Thanks your reply.
I want input type="button". Don't want anchor link.

Comment: Looked great!  Until I tried it in IE9... :-(  Nice work nevertheless.